# stripe with axios problem: .createServer is not a function

Tags: javascript, axios, stripe-payments

Try to make the front end from the stripe work, When I open a page or generate the index.html I get the problem from:

This problem makes the other methods in the program to stop working.

[image: Error]

Her is the source code

stripe.js

```
/* eslint-disable*/
import axios from 'axios';
import { showAlert } from './alerts';
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe(
  process.env.PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY
);


export const bookTour = async (tourId) => {
  try {
    //1) Get Checkout session from API
    
    const session = await axios(
      `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/bookings/checkout-session/${tourId}`
    );
    console.log(session);
    //2) Create checkout from + chanre credit card
    await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: session.data.session.id,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    showAlert('error', err);
  }
};
```

bookingRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bookingController = require('../controller/bookingController');
const authController = require('../controller/authController');

const router = express.Router();

router.use(authController.protect);

router.get(
    '/checkout-session/:tourId', 
    authController.protect, 
    bookingController.getCheckoutSession
    );


module.exports = router;
```

try `` `stripe.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = require('http').createServer(function(){}).timeout` ``

But I steal have the error if I put this in the stripe.js How can I fix this problem in my code?

bookingController.js

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const Tour = require('../models/tourModel');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');
const factory = require('../controller/handlerFactory');
const Booking = require('../models/bookingModel')

exports.getCheckoutSession = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // 1) Get the currently booked tour
  const tour = await Tour.findById(req.params.tourId);
  // 2) Create checkout session
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_type: ['card'],
    success_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/`,
    cancel_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/tour//${tour.slug}`,
    customer_email: req.user.email,
    client_reference_id: req.params.tourId,
    mode:'payment',
    line_itmes: [
      {
        name: `${tour.name} Tour `,
        description: tour.summery,
        images: [`https://www.natours.dev/img/tours/${tour.imageCover}`],
        amount: tour.price * 100,
        currency: 'usd',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
  });
  // 3) Create session as response
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    session,
  });
});

exports.createBookingCheckout = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // This is only TEMPORARY, because it's UNSECURE: everyone can make bookings without paying
  const { tour, user, price } = req.query;

  if (!tour && !user && !price) return next();
  await Booking.create({ tour, user, price });

  res.redirect(req.originalUrl.split('?')[0]);
});

exports.createBooking = factory.createOne(Booking);
exports.getBooking = factory.getOne(Booking);
exports.getAllBookings = factory.getAll(Booking);
exports.updateBooking = factory.updateOne(Booking);
exports.deleteBooking = factory.deleteOne(Booking);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are attempting to load the Stripe Node SDK on the frontend which won't work (this is a backend package) as opposed to Stripe.JS. You instead should be importing `'@stripe/stripe-js';` as shown here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#import-as-a-side-effect